# Active directory Invalid token in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, active-directory

I am developing a small application using Xamarin forms, I would like to implement (MSAL) active directory, I have configured everything and getting token, after that I have checked in postman while I am getting below
{"success": false," message": "Sorry, you are not authorized to access this API. Please make sure you are logged in!","data":null}

```
I tried sending the web request to server while I am getting HTTP response below
    
    {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers: { Transfer-Encoding: chunked Server: Kestrel WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid" X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 12h X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 4999 X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 2021-07-19T14:20:05.8546118Z Date: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 02:20:05 GMT Content-Type: text/plain }}
    
 Here I tried the code below, please help me to resolve this issue
    App.xaml.cs
    public static IPublicClientApplication PCA = null;
    public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };
    
     PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Constants.ClientID)
              .WithRedirectUri($"msauth://{Constants.AppId}/{Constants.SIGNATURE_HASH}")
              .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Constants.TenentID}")
              .Build();
    
    Viewmodel signin command i called SignInAsync
    
     public async Task SignInAsync()
            {
                Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
                IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                try
                {
                    IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
                    authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(App.Scopes, firstAccount)
                                            .ExecuteAsync();
                    Session.Instance.TokenValueFromApp = authResult.AccessToken;
                }
                catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)                                                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                                                    .ExecuteAsync();
                        Session.Instance.TokenValueFromApp = authResult.AccessToken;    
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex2)
                    {
    
                    }
                }
            }
```

Mainactivity.cs
App.ParentWindow = this;
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

```
    Manifest.xml
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
    <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="msal{clientid}" android:host="auth" /> //here i am pasting client id
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="msauth" android:host="{bundleid}" android:path="/{signaturehash}" /> //here i am pasting bundle id and signature hash
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
        <queries>
            <package android:name="com.azure.authenticator" />
            <package android:name="{bundle id}" />   // here i am pasting a bundle id
            <package android:name="com.microsoft.windowsintune.companyportal" />
            <intent>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent>
            <intent>
                <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
            </intent>
        </queries>
```

Comment: you need to post the relevant code

Comment: Hi Jason, Please let me know, if i am anything wrong

Comment: You could make a breakpoint to see if you could successfully get the accesstoken.

Comment: Yes I am getting token, I said already, it is saying that invalid token while request to webservice

Comment: 1) redirect url need to add oauth token and scope tenantid+user.read